# Issue with runtime created image targets Vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am creating an `AR/OCR` application which a user will use to take a photo of a piece of text, with `tesseract` providing `OCR` functionality. Once the text is recognized, the intention is that the first word will be used as an image target at runtime.

I've got as far as saving the cropped section (effectively a text box) around the first word. However, I'm having real trouble getting the image target to work. I tried using a sample taken image target from testing in the actual Target Creator section of the `Vuforia` website, but it's coming up as a 0-star rating as an image target.

I'm guessing as it's going to be such a small target. It's looking for it's not going to be ideal. I'm really not sure how to approach this or improve chances of getting the image target (albeit a very small section to be used as image target) to work correctly. Everything in the project is hinging on this step working and I'm badly stuck!

Tried exporting the image target to check the correct section is being used for target purposes.

Tried manually adding a sample to the Vuforia Target Manager to see if this could be used as target

Answer (score 0):

Typically, text is not recommended for Vuforia Engine Image Targets. Please review the following article for best practices regarding image-based targets: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/objects/best-practices-designing-and-developing-image-based-targets